# Is it possible to convert color to array?

Tags: metapost, metafun

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to convert `color`s to arrays with `{red|green|blue}part` and this macro

```
vardef arrayFromColors(suffix $)(text c) =
  save i_ ; i_ = 0 ;
  numeric $[][] ;
  for i = c:
    for j = 0 upto 2:
      if     j = 0: $[i_][j] = redpart   i ;
      elseif j = 1: $[i_][j] = greenpart i ;
      else:         $[i_][j] = bluepart  i ;
      fi
    endfor ;
    i_ := i_+1 ;
  endfor ;
enddef ;
```

which is used like that

```
arrayFromColors(A)((0,1,2),(3,4,5));
```

but it always fail with this error:

> metafun         > log > error: Not implemented: decimal(unknown numeric)

So, is it possible to convert `color`s to arrays like that?

Comment: Can you provide full format of `MWE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found what was wrong.

I attempted to print a full array, `A[1]` for example, with `message`, but it seems that `message` can not print a full array in the compilation log.

I tried with another array, declared by hand, to check

```
numeric a[] ;
a[0] = 0 ;
a[1] = 1 ;
a[2] = 30 ;
message a ;
```

and it fails with the same error

> metafun > log > error: Not implemented: decimal(unknown numeric)

too.

However, when accessing values one by one, `A[1][1]` for example, `message` correctly prints the value `4` as it should be with the little piece of code from my question.

Comment: yes, after `numeric a[]`, the symbolic token `a` is a numeric variable with an empty suffix, not a reference to an array.   MP does not really have the concept of an array.

You are also a victim of a bit of `metafun` syntactic sugar.  In plain MP `message` would have given you a `Not a string` error.  Metafun kindly translates numerics to strings for you using `decimal` but in this case that gives you an very obscure error, since you have to know that the format has enhanced `message` for you.

I know I am biassed but this sort of extra complexity is why I prefer plain MP.